# How to compare two tables and replace nulls with values from other table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I am working on some assignment, where we have two tables with same/different columns.If a record of `table A` has some column values as `null` then that has to update to value in `table B`,Vice versa.

`table A`

```
id | code | type
1  | null | A
2  | null | null
3  | 123  | C
```

`table B`

```
id | code | type
1  | 456 | A
2  | 789 | A1
3  | null  | C
```

what I have worked so far

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").load("C:\\Users\\System2\\Videos\\1199_data\\d1_1.csv");
    Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").load("C:\\Users\\System2\\Videos\\1199_data\\d2_1.csv");



df1
    .as("a").join(df2.as("b"))
    .where("a.id== b.id")
    .withColumn("a.code", 
             functions.when(
                     df1.col("code").isNull(),


                     df2.col("code")  )

).show();
```

Required Output

`table C`

```
id | code | type
1  | 456 | A
2  | 789 | A1
3  | 123  | C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the coalesce function?

```
df1.join(df2, "id")
   .select(df1("id"), 
           coalesce(df1("code"), 
           df2("code")).as("code"), 
           coalesce(df1("type"), 
           df2("type")).as("type"))
```

And output:

```
+---+----+----+
| id|code|type|
+---+----+----+
|  1| 456|   A|
|  2| 789|  A1|
|  3| 123|   C|
+---+----+----+
```

Comment: `.withColumnRenamed("coalesce(code, code)", "Code")` is it the only way to rename or in `select` function iteslf possible

Comment: you can rename the column afterwards using the alias function on column.  (see my edited post)